# Ninjago lightning and fire dragons

Tags: sets, shopping, ninjago

I am searching (to buy) the lighting dragon and the fire dragon from the Ninjago series. I am not interested in other parts of those sets, I'm just searching for the dragons themselves.

I have searched Bricklink and Ebay to check if there are individual dragons sold, but I could not find them.

Does anyone have any hint where I can buy those dragons?

Comment: Just to clarify are we referring to the dragons from [2507](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=2507-1) and [2521](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=2521-1)?

Comment: yes, the dragons of those sets are the ones i'm searching for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of several possibilities:

1. Just be patient. They'll probably come up on bricklink or ebay eventually.
2. Buy the complete sets and sell off the parts / assemblies that don't interest you.
3. Buy the sets with someone else and split them for the parts / models that interest each of you.
4. Get the instructions, and buy the parts to make the dragons individually.
5. Create your own dragons from the any parts you already have or can get easily.

It depends on how much you want the dragons. If you really *need* them, I suggest (2) might be your best bet.

Comment: I tend to buy a set for a certain feature and use the parts else ware (point 3). In some cases LEGO sellers on Ebay split sets into key components (like each carriage of a train) and sell each component at an inflated price.

Comment: It is just that i'm not colelcting ninjago series, just dragons of any kind (expecially lego ones), so i should buy the sets and sell what i don't need

Comment: @Terix that's probably your best bet, the problem is that the dragons are brick-built, so I'm not too sure if people will sell them separately. Keep in mind there's probably not going to be any BrickLink entry for them, so it will be harder for sellers who would want to do that. Well, they may list the set and say "warning, dragon only" or something, but it won't be easy for you to find. So what I'm saying is, don't count too much on option 1.